# How to preserve original fragment identifier in Spring OAuth2 server auth redirects

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I've got a client `@SpringBootApplication` with `@EnableOAuth2Sso` and `security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri` & `security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri` setup such that it redirects my users to my OAuth2 server for authentication using Authorization Code (*not implicit!*).

My OAuth2 server uses `@EnableAuthorizationServer` and a `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` extending class to set everything up server side with little customization.

Now my client app hosts an Angular website that uses fragment identifiers for navigation. Users can bookmark/share URLs containing these fragment identifiers to get back to specific pages later. However, these URLs only work when the user is already authenticated, otherwise the fragment identifier is lost in the OAuth2 server redirect/login dance.

I've read the following blog post to identify the problem:
http://codetunnel.io/how-to-persist-url-hash-fragments-across-a-login-redirect/
In short: The fragment identifiers are never sent to the server, only retained by the browser in redirects, but lost on POST requests. The blog post recommends a workaround by using client side JavaScript to insert the hash fragment into the login form redirect_uri field.

I'm having some trouble translating the above knowledge to my application however; I can see the fragment identifiers are retained in the redirects:

- `client/app#mypage` 302
- `client/login#mypage` 302
- `server/oauth/authorize#mypage` 302
- `server/logon#mypage`

The last page is a custom stylized login page of mine that I can insert JavaScript code on. This page contains a form which POSTs to `./logon`, after which the fragment identifier is lost.

What can I do to retain the fragment identifier in the final redirect back to the user?

Answer (score 2):

And in the process of working out the above question I was able to (quite easily) fix the issue in the end:

I (already) override both the `/logon` and `/oauth/confirm_access` pages to inject a small JQuery JavaScript snippet:

```
// Manually insert the hash fragment to preserve angular app pages in redirect
// As per: http://codetunnel.io/how-to-persist-url-hash-fragments-across-a-login-redirect/
$(function () {
    var $form = $('#form');
    $form.attr('action', $form.attr('action') + window.location.hash);
});
```

This appends the fragment identifier to the form POST action, meaning the browser retains it throughout the login process without sending it to the server.

I had previously attempted to work with a custom `RedirectResolver`, but that approach came up empty so far. If anyone else has a working version feel free to contribute!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was also able to fix it with a custom login page, but without having to use JavaScript.  In the `form` tag, I simply left the `action` blank, which will cause it to default to the current URL, including any fragment that might be present.

If you do a "view source" on the login page that Spring gives you out of the box, you will notice that the action is explicitly set to "/login" which is what causes the fragment to disappear when using their default login page.